List Mapping: ForMember configuration when mapping is conditional for DateTime properties , destination object DateTime properties always has default
Because my Issue on Github was closed I am opening a thread here.
GitHub issue
Source type:
public class ATest1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

Destination type:
public class ATest2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    }

Mapping configuration:
        CreateMap<ATest, ATest2>()
            .ForMember(x => x.DateCreated, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest) 
                =>
            {
                return dest.Id <= 0 ? DateTime.UtcNow : dest.DateCreated;
            }))
            .EqualityComparison((source, destination) => source.Id == destination.Id);

Versions:
Automapper: 12.0.1
Automapper.Collection: 9.0.0
EF Core: 8.0.3
Expected behavior
This mapping was provided for mapping List of entites defined above. My expectation is that when I will check if it is existing entity or not (has database Id or not), based on this condition I can leave the DateCreated value of existing item as it is and just set the DateCreated value for new items.
Actual behavior
But after mapping the lists, existing items DateCreated value is always set to DateTime.MinValue. I debugged and I saw that I am not getting the destination object values for DateTime.
I already tried the .Condition() and .PreCondition() methods but the same happens.
See images below:
Image 1
Image 2
Image 3
Image 4
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong ?
It would be good if someone can explain the behaviour here.
IMPORTANT: Just to mention that if I do the mapping for single object it works as expected.

After spending some time, I found the answer.
I forgot to add

AddCollectionMappers()

method to the root of the configuration as suggested in the documentation:
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection?tab=readme-ov-file#how-to-add-to-automapper
This is why the list was recreated and somehow only the DateTime values were not mapped properly.
After adding this line the mapping was done for existing collection without recreating it, so expectation is met.
